# AJAX и множество непрерывных запросов

Tags: jquery, ajax

Вопрос общего характера для самообразования. Предположим есть форма, куда вносятся какие-то данные (например, поиск пользователя по имени), далее используя `jQuery.ajax({...});` делаем POST запрос, проверяем указанные данные и возвращаем ответ.

Что если пользователь начнёт непрерывно жать на отправку запроса? Можно ли навредить сайту непрерывно отправляя запрос? Пусть даже с одинаковым ответом?

Если да, как с этим бороться? Записывать количество нажатий? Или сделать таймаут на запрос?

Спасибо

Comment: я бы поставил таймаут с красивым обратным отсчетом для повторного использования формы..а навредить сайту - вряд ли..ну будет сервер обрабатывать туда сюда один и тот же запрос..ну будет возвращать один и тот же ответ..я думаю ничего существенного. Пусть знающие поправят если шо

Comment: Вы лучше скажите что у вас на бэке стоит? Помимо визуальной блокировки на JS нужно еще сделать ограничение запросов на сервере, чтобы не тушили сайт постоянными запросами. Поэтому заглушка вам особо не поможет, если у вас бэкэнд не защищен.

Comment: @MoloF А что у нас "таймеры" можно только на фронте делать ?) Что мешает занести в базу время последнего нажатия + 10 сек и сравнивать его с текущим ? ) Ну или как сказано вами - огран. запросов

Comment: @MoloF если рассматривать частный случай, можно взять WordPress. Для запросов использовать `wp_ajax_nopriv_` и `admin-ajax.php` + самописная функция с выдачей результатов.

Comment: @AlexanderGoroshev [Есть ли ограничения на звонки в WordPress.org API?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184616) , [Ограничение скорости AJAX-запросов в WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/354833) . Я нашел информацию как это делают другие люди: кэшируют свои запросы. Добавляют рекапчу. Ограничивают кол-во запросов с помощью NGINX.

Comment: @MoloF спасибо за наводку. Я соединил запрос с капчей 3й и она срабатывает бесконечно, то есть, отдаёт score 0.9. Сейчас хочу попробовать вторую, где есть физическое взаимодействие

Comment: А ещё вот [такое](https://github.com/nemac/ajaxthrottle) нашел. Но, если всё соберёте и какой-нить пример накидаете в ответе, можно будет принять. Как минимум, я понял, что оставлять не стоит без внимания. Спасибо